# Problems with accessing inside braintree's arrays

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, paypal, braintree

I dont know why this is working but I am trying to get the timezone inside the array

```
$transaction = $gateway->subscription()->find($_GET["id"]);
echo '<pre>' , var_dump($transaction->billingPeriodStartDate) , '</pre>';
```

This shows

```
object(DateTime)#13 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-04-10 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

But when I decide to try to get date

```
$transaction = $gateway->subscription()->find($_GET["id"]);
echo '<pre>' , var_dump($transaction->billingPeriodStartDate->timezone) , '</pre>';
```

This shows up on my screen

```
Notice:  Undefined property: DateTime::$timezone in C:\xampp\htdocs\finalfees\braintree_php_example\public_html\transaction.php on line 10

NULL
```

Comment: You would need to use [`getTimezone()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimezone.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the properties do this:

```
$transaction = (object)(array) $gateway->subscription()->find($_GET["id"]);
```

Or if you just want the timezone, not the actually full array you see in var_dump:

```
$transaction->getTimezone()->getName()
```